# survey/book on adaptive/self-tuning of PI controllers?

Tags: reference-request, control-systems

Can someone point me towards a good book or survey article on adaptive/self-tuning of PI controllers?

All I can find online are articles which are either vague or heavy on theory.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitively not a satisfying answer, but what you call "adaptive" in combination with a pi-controller is commonly called `gain-scheduling` or `lpv-gain-scheduling` (lpv = linear parameter varying). Maybe that helps you find a book.

Comment: +1 -- half the work in searching for information is figuring out what terms to use

Answer (score 2):

Typically Self tuning controllers are done in the digital domain. You may want to look into Least Squares Method for controller tuning.